# Deriving the Heisenberg uncertainty principle from the wave packet

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, fourier-transform, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

[image]

How did we get the C-17, is it possible to derive the Heisenberg uncertainty principle from the wave packet?
could you recommend readings to help me understand this better.

Answer (score 0):

Consider two wavepackets. One that has a very consistent wavelength inside, and one that is highy localized to a single point.

The former allows you a high confidence in determining its momentum, but low confidence in finding its position.

The latter gives you a low confidence in determining its momentum, but a high confidence in finding its position.

The same can be said for energy and time.

That is to say, you can't simultaneously have high confidence in knowing both. Ergo, Heisenberg uncertainty.

Comment: Hey! thanks for the answer, I don't understand the paragraph above C-17 and the relation too, how did they come to the conclusion that (delta k)(x-x0)=1.